# HEROKU FLASK "No Web Processes Running" error

Tags: flask, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my web application to Heroku but after following all the steps needed and loading my web page, it says application error. I've tried probably almost all of the solutions here in stackoverflow but I can't seem to overcome my problem.

```
...at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET...
```

Comment: whats the web framework you are using?

Comment: im using flask.

Comment: if its  not scaled run this command ```heroku ps:scale web=1```
then check  gunicorn present in  pip  if then create  a file named ```Procfile``` in root of the project add the following line ```web: gunicorn app:app```. where app is your  app name

Comment: i tried `heroku ps:scale web=1` but it returns me this: `Couldn't find that process type (web).`. I also made a procfile `web: gunicorn application:app` where application is my application.py.

Comment: thats because  it missing procfile in the server. try adding the file  in git  and push again

Comment: thank you for your help. i did it but still it returns an application error [link](https://bruceproject1.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: in my application.py i have this in my code: `if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))`

Comment: could  u post the  heroku logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215030/discussion-between-lionel-vsv-and-bruce-salcedo).